# Is there such thing CASE expression in JPQL?

Tags: java, oracle, orm, jpa

Let say there is a table:

```
TableA:Field1, Field2, Field3
```

and associated JPA entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TableA")
public class TableA{
  @Id
  @Column(name="Field1")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name="Field2")
  private Long field2;

  @Column(name="Field3")
  private Long field3;

  //... more associated getter and setter...
}
```

Is there any way to construct a JPQL statement that loosely translated to this SQL, ie how to translated the case expression to JPQL?

```
select field1,
case
  when field2 = 1 then 'One'
  when field2 = 2 then 'Two'
  else 'Other number'
end,
field3
from tableA;
```

Answer (score 132, accepted):

It has been added in JPA 2.0

**Usage:**

```
SELECT e.name, CASE WHEN (e.salary >= 100000) THEN 1 WHEN (e.salary < 100000) THEN 2 ELSE 0 END FROM Employee e
```

**Ref:** http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL_BNF#New_in_JPA_2.0

Comment: Does this works for dual as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51565156/convert-oracle-case-statement-to-jpql-or-jpa-repository-query ?

Answer (score 3):

There is certainly such thing in Hibernate so when you use Hibernate as your JPA provider then you can write your query as in this example:

```
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE MNPOperationPrintDocuments o SET o.fileDownloadCount = CASE WHEN o.fileDownloadCount IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE (o.fileDownloadCount + 1) END " +
                                            " WHERE o IN (:operations)");
    query.setParameter("operations", mnpOperationPrintDocumentsList);

    int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the event listeners provided by Jpa to do something when you load one row of the db, ie:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableA")
public class TableA {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Field1")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "Field2")
    private Long field2;

    @Column(name = "Field3")
    private Long field3;

    // ... more associated getter and setter...

    @Transient
    private String field4;

    @PostLoad
    private void onLoad() {
        if (field2 != null) {
            switch (field2.intValue()) {
            case 1:
                field4 = "One";
                break;
            case 2:
                field4 = "Two";
                break;
            default:
                field4 = "Other Number";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(the field4 not persist in the db)

(take this like an workaround to "non implemented feature in JPA" like case statements)