# Convert SQL with SUM(IF) statements to JPA JPQL

Tags: sql, jpa, jpql

Is there anyway to represent this sql query in JPQL, I am having difficulty with the SUM(IF) parts. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
SELECT username, 
SUM(IF(`first` = firstPar,1,0)) firstCount,
SUM(IF(`second` = secondPar,1,0)) secondCount,
SUM(IF(`third` = thirdPar,1,0)) thirdCount
FROM rounds
LEFT JOIN courses
ON 1
GROUP BY username
```

Not a duplicate as suggested question does not use the JOIN or multiple SUM's

Comment: Do you know how to do just plain `SUM()`?

Comment: Yes but this needs to be the sum of rows in rounds (column first,second etc) where the value matches the column first, second etc in courses

Comment: IF should be replaced with CASE for JPQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there such thing CASE expression in JPQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427447/is-there-such-thing-case-expression-in-jpql) - assuming it's `JPA 2.0`.

Comment: @NeilStockton I changed the IF's to CASE but it did not work

PM 77 I looked at that link but it does not include SUM statement or JOIN for two tables

Comment: errm, define HOW you "changed the IF's to CASE" ... in the question. And then define "it did not work" because all "did not work" have actual facts behind them, like exceptions which are clearly important.

Comment: Sorry Neil I should have explained, I tried changing to CASE and adding the WHEN and THEN keywords and also the END keyword like below
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN('first' = c.firstPar) THEN 1), "
    + "SUM(CASE WHEN('second' = c.secondPar) THEN 1), "
    + "SUM(CASE WHEN('third' = c.thirdPar) THEN 1) "
    + "END FROM Rounds a JOIN Courses.course_name c GROUP BY a.username");

Comment: which is obviously incorrect syntax. A CASE, WHEN and the END have to be structured ... whereas yours is all over the place. You need 3 case statements there. And likely the (secret) exception you would have received would have hinted at that

Comment: @NeilStockton no the exception just says "unexpected token: ) near line 1" no mention of CASE statements and I have 3 case statements in it?
Can you advise on the correct syntax for this query please

Comment: Read the JPA spec, or any JPA docs, it tells you. http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/jpql.html#case

Comment: Had a read through a couple but could not understand the SUM(CASE usage, if anyone can translate this query I would really appreciate it thanks