# How can i achieve MYSQL case function in Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

i am a newbie.
can anyone help me to achieve MYSQL Case statement in spring boot.
just like using findBy.

Comment: Hey, your DB queries will never dependent on spring boot. You should be using Hibernate, JPA or some ORM or JDBC. Please provide some code from where you are trying to write the queries. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427447/is-there-such-thing-case-expression-in-jpql if it helps you.

Comment: sorry sreenath i want to use Spring Data JPA Repository

Comment: Then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427447/is-there-such-thing-case-expression-in-jpql might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you are looking for, but I think you want JPA query annotation.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details