# Convert Oracle Case Statement to JPQL or JPA repository query?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I am new to the `JPA2.0` world, but I hope case statements can also be mapped to `JPQL` or using `JPARepository`. I am using Oracle 12c.

How to convert below statement to JPQL to repository query?

```
select case when exists (select 1 from ABC_OWNER.BANK_ACCT where ACC_NUM = ?) then 'Y' else 'N' end from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think JPA does not recognize the word 'exists'. So, that's how I implement in projects I work to:

```
select case when COUNT(*) > 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end from ABC_OWNER.BANK_ACCT where ACC_NUM = ?
```