# Override column selection in jpa

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

I need to select an integer column (int) by left joining its entity.

When there are no rows, its value is "null", what I need is to have 0 instead of null.

I searched for an annotation or a way to override the select query with no result. Note that I'm using eclipselink.

I am searching for something that always makes the selection of the column "coalesce(columnName,0)" instead of columnName.

**EDIT:**

A code Sample:

```
public class parent{
 @Id
 private int id;
 private String field1;
 private String field2;
 private List<Child> children;
}

public class Child{
 @Id
 private int id;
 private int myNumber;
 private String field;
}
```

The JPA Query is similar to

```
SELECT p FROM parent p LEFT JOIN p.children c ON c.field = 'aaa' WHERE p.field1 = 'bbb'
```

The translation of this query would be:

```
SELECT t0.id, t0.field1, t0.field2, t1.id, t1.myNumber, t1.field
FROM parent t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN child t1 on t0.id = t1.parent_id AND t1.field = 'aaaa
WHERE t0.field1 = 'bbb'
```

In the case where there are no rows in CHILD, the field: t1.myNumber will have the value null.

To fix it, in Sql statement, normally I will use coalesce(t1.myNumber,0). So the query will be:

```
SELECT t0.id, t0.field1, t0.field2, t1.id, coalesce(t1.myNumber,0), t1.field
FROM parent t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN child t1 on t0.id = t1.parent_id AND t1.field = 'aaaa
WHERE t0.field1 = 'bbb'
```

What I need is to accomplish this result using some annotation, or any other tool if exists, whithout changing the JPA query if possible.

Comment: Why not return back an entity instance that you can just abstract out the null value with 0?  This allows the entity to be cached and used for other queries as well. Otherwise, use the case statement https://stackoverflow.com/a/7308668/496099

Comment: Thanks for reply @Chris, but this value is coming as null because there is no entity at all -> all this entity field were returned null (bcs of left join)> In regard to the case statement, I can't use it cause I'm selecting the all entity (select e From EntityName e Left Join e.OtherEntity...)

Comment: Show your query and what the result you are looking at working with. the case statement works with data queries, allowing you to return null if the field is null regardless if it is null because of a left join or other reason.