# Spring Data JPA sorting on additional column returned by query

Tags: spring, sorting, spring-data-jpa, pagination, case

I have a Table "team" with below structure:

| Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `id` | uuid |  | not null |  |
| `team_name` | character varying(200) |  | not null |  |
| `admin_group` | uuid |  | not null |  |
| `lead_group` | uuid |  | not null |  |
| `user_group` | uuid |  | not null |  |

I am using Spring Data JPA and need to execute query equivalent to:

```
SELECT *,
       CASE
           WHEN lead_group IN groupList THEN 3
           WHEN admin_group IN groupList THEN 2
           WHEN user_group IN groupList THEN 1
           ELSE 0 END AS role
FROM team;
```

Here `groupList` is list of all groups user is part of. I get this info from another service.

What is the best way to do it using Spring Data JPA? I also need to support sorting based on all columns and pagination. Do I add a additional field 'role' in my Team entity or create a separate class altogether to collect the data from the query?

Comment: I have question regarding `groupList `. Can you read  `groupList ` directly inside the current query, for example by sub query or will you need to pass the `groupList ` outside by query parameter?

Comment: @Eugene : I'll need to pass groupList from outside as a parameter..!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achive it:

- you should define DB view using this query and define entity/repo in your code for read only.
- you can use annotation Query and Pagination object in repoitory like:

  ```
  @Repository
    public interface GroupTeamRepository extends 
    JpaRepository<GroupTeamEntity, UUID>, 
    JpaSpecificationExecutor<GroupTeamEntity>

        @Query(value="""
        SELECT *,
            CASE
              WHEN lead_group IN groupList THEN 3
              WHEN admin_group IN groupList THEN 2
              WHEN user_group IN groupList THEN 1
              ELSE 0 END AS role
            FROM team
        """, nativeQuery = true)
        Page<GroupTeamEntity> getGroupedTeam(Pageable pageable);
  ```

There is a really useful feature: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications

Answer (score 0):

That is a tricky one, since you state that you obtain the `groupList` from a different service.

For a first option lets challenge this assumption.
If you instead could get the `groupList` through a function call or inner select from the database you can get a nice solution if you also happen to use Hibernate: [Use the `@Formula` annotation to make the computation a field of your entity](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-calculate-entity-attributes-formula/). Paging and sorting should work just fine with that approach.
Alternatively you can join the information to your table using a database view and map your entity to that view. Just make sure to make the `role` read only.

If you really can't obtain it in the database by normal means, maybe we can do a trick: Put that information in the database before you start querying for your `team`. Create something, that is wrapped around your service, e.g. a [web filter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter) or an [Aspect](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop). It would obtain `groupList` and make it available in the database. You could simply write it into a table, using JPA or JDBC, or you could use something more fancy like for example Oracles temporary tables, which might yield performance benefits. Depending on how you make the list available in the database you can then map it to a read only field of your entity or use the `@Formula` annotation mentioned above.

If you really can't get the `groupList` in any other way then through a parameter things get a little more tricky. You'll have to resort to custom method implementations on your repository and work with JPA directly. You'd have to create your query manually including the required sorting and pagination, probably using the Criteria API.
Since we are talking a single entity, the work involved for this is limited and depending on your experience with JPA on the one hand and lower level database stuff on the other hand, might even be easier than the other solutions.

Note: [translating the SQL case expression to JPQL shouldn't be too difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427447/is-there-such-thing-case-expression-in-jpql).

Answer (score 0):

You can define role as one of field (may be `@Transient` ?) in your `Team` entity.

And as you mentioned you are getting `groupList` from external service so I think use of `ExampleMatcher` will be good for your requirement.

Below psudo-code does following:

1. Create `Team` entity & against each `group` in `groupList` it sets `group` value for all 3 fields.
2. `ExampleMatcher.matchingAny()` will check for any of predicate if it matches.
3. You have set pageIndex & pageSize so that entire dataset won't get loaded into memory.
4. Returned `page` can be used to transform returned entity so that we can populate role field based on your requirement.

   ```
    Team team=new Team();
    int pageIndex=10;
    int pageSize=10;

    for(Group p : groupList){
    team.setLead_group(p);
    team.setAdmin_group(p);
    team.setUser_group(p);
    ExampleMatcher exampleMatcher=ExampleMatcher.matchingAny().withMatcher("lead_group", exact()).withMatcher("admin_group",
                        exact()).withMatcher("user_group",
                        exact());
    Example<Team> ex = Example.of(team, exampleMatcher);
    Page<Team> page;
    do{
     page= jpaRepository.findAll(ex,PageRequest.of(pageIndex, pageSize, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "id")));

     List<Team> ls= page.getContent();
     //apply transformation for each Team element of ls & do any further operation as you want
    }while(page.hasNext());}
   ```

You can use any `stream` operations which can do transformation or simply iterate over returned `ls` & do transformation:

```
public Team transform(Team t){
  if(null!=t.getUser_group()){
    t.setRole(1);
  }
  //and so on;
  return t;
}
```